# How to call a function inside a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, linked-list

So i am trying to learn class based or OOP if you want to call it and i am writing a linked List. So i have created a class and written certain functions. I am having a really hard time figuring out how can i call these functions so i can `console.log` the output. In Javascript i can simply call the some function by `console.log(functionName)` and see the output but how do i do it with class based functions?

I just want to call all these functions inside the linkedList class such as `size`, `insertFirst` etc and console log the outputs. How can i achieve the same?

I am new to the OOP world so please excuse any ignorance or if you feel it is a silly question.

Check this Code:-

```
 class Node {
    constructor(data, next = null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
    }

  insertFirst(data) {
      this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
  }  

  size() {
      let counter = 0;
      let node = this.head;

      while(node) {
          counter++
          node = node.next
      }
      return counter;
  }
}

const list = console.log(new LinkedList());
list.head = console.log(new Node(10));
```

Appreciate all the help!! Thank you

Comment: Wrapping your constructor calls with `console.log` logs the object, then throws it away and assigns the return value of `console.log`, which is `undefined` to your `const list` and `list.head` vars. Just do `const list = new LinkedList()` and log it later with `console.log(list)` on a different line if you want. `console.log` displays output and has nothing to do with helping call methods as you seem to indicate.

Comment: @ggorlen Ohhh i see!! That made sense i think!! btw thanks for the tip!! I can finally see my output in the console now!! If you add this as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- EDIT: I've modified your classes a little bit. I think the `print` method that I wrote in the `LinkedList` class might be helpful for you, and I prefer the `setHead` method to `insertFirst` --

```js
class Node {
    constructor(data, next = null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
    }

  setHead(node) {
      this.head = node;
  }  

  size() {
      let counter = 0;
      let node = this.head;

      while(node) {
          counter++
          node = node.next
      }
      return counter;
  }

  print() {
      let node = this.head;
      while(node) {
          console.log(node.data);
          node = node.next
      }
  }
}

let myList = new LinkedList();
let bob = new Node("bob");
let joe = new Node("joe", bob);
let carl = new Node("carl", joe)
let alice = new Node("alice", carl)
myList.setHead(alice);

// print the data in the nodes
console.log(carl.data);
console.log(bob.data);
console.log(joe.data);
console.log(alice.data);

// print size
console.log(myList.size())

// print the entire list
myList.print()
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!! This works and this was great because it has sorta started to make sense to me!!

Answer (score 1):

assigning `console.log()` to a variable will always result to undefined
you may want to try this

```
const lists =new LinkedList()
console.log(lists)
lists.head = new Node(10)
console.log(lists.head)
```

to call a function inside a class you first create an object from the class using the constructor and pass any values to the contractor
and then you simply call the function like this

```js
class classobject{
    constructor (apple){
     this.apple=apple
    }
     printName(){
      console.log(this.apple,"apple")}
      }
    
    const apple= new classobject("granny ") 
     apple.printName()
```